# Cannot write to my csv file from Oracle database using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, csv, odbc, fputcsv

I think I used fputcsv correctly.My database table contains two columns with dates and numbers in both columns.  I use an oracle database and a windows 2008 server.

```
//Connexion BDD Oracle
$connect = odbc_connect("oraclesrc", "xe", "sec123");

$query = "select * from timedata";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

$numOF = 0;
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
    $emp = odbc_result($result, 1);
    $time = odbc_result($result, 2);
    $numOF++;
    echo $emp; 
    echo $time;     
}

$fp = fopen('testfile.csv', 'w');
foreach ($row as $result) {
    fputcsv($fp, $result);
}
fclose($fp);

odbc_close($connect);
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You wrote a WHILE Loop to process the result set, but you didnt write the csv file in there ??

Comment: I have to put my foreach in my while?

Comment: Does the while loop produce any output?

Comment: `$row` does not seem to exists before you attempt to foreach loop over it ??

Comment: No it doesn't exist, what should I put in its place?

Comment: Overall it might be more efficient to use the native PHP OCI8 extension instead of ODBC. Or use SQL*Plus :) https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database

Answer (score 2):

The while loop fetches the result rows one at a time. If you change to use `odbc_fetch_array($result)` you will get an Assoc array exactly as `fputcsv()` want to see it.

```
//Connexion BDD Oracle
$connect = odbc_connect("oraclesrc", "xe", "sec123");
$query = "select * from timedata";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

$fp = fopen('testfile.csv', 'w');

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
odbc_close($connect);
```

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you very much for your explanation